# What is the linguistic term for nouns which are used as verb infinitive?

Tags: terminology

What is the term to for the nouns which are formed from verbs or stems, whether as expressing action (revolution; commendation), or a state (contrition; starvation), or associated meanings (relation; temptation)?

Comment: deverbal is a common term for nouns/adjectives/adverbs derived from verbs and would include infinitives

Comment: Looking at your examples, *deverbal nominalization* is probably the term you're looking for. But these would be used as nouns; if you indeed mean "used as a verb infinitive" rather than "derived from a verb", you'd have to specify further what you mean.

Comment: @Tristan, that is not exactly what I''m looking for. I mean specifically, the deverbals which can be used instead of infinitives. same semantic.